# Linq with strong typed data in 2sxc

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

This was a common use in dynamic code:

```
@foreach(var myData in AsList(App.Data["Data"]))
{
    foreach(var x in AsList(myData.Specifications as object).Where(a => a.toApp)) { ... }
}
```

But in typed data, this always results in one error or another.

```
@foreach(var myData in App.Data.GetAll<Data>();)
{
    foreach(var x in myData.Specifications).Where(a => a.toApp)) { ... }
}
```

myData.Specifications is an entity field linking to the data type DataSpecs.

How can these entities data types be properly implemented in strong typed code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before RazorTyped, .Specifications would just return an object. Now you need to return either an [ITypedItem](https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Data.ITypedItem.html) or IEnumerable<ITypedItem>, since you named it plural, I'll assume the latter.

So instead try,

```
    foreach(var x in myData.Children("Specifications")
      .Where( ... )
    ) 
    { 
      ... 
    }
```

But if its not 1:many, and 1:1 instead, here is an example that I hope makes sense.

You have a content-type named Project. A field in Project named Client is an Entity pointing to the content-type Clients. So each Project is for 1 Client. Now the Clients content-type has a field named Status (a string dropdown). So now I only want to show Projects for *active clients*.

To do this, my where looks like this:

```
  .Where(p => p.Child("Client").String("Status") == "active")
```

If another example might help, I also wrote [an article a few months back](https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/17212/Related-Data-in-2sxc-with-RazorTyped) while 2sxc was v16+ but not yet evolved to the newer hotness of things like `.GetAll<Data>(). It shows data relationships and iterating through getting it working, and then using .Parents() to make handling a many:many relationship make sense, be readable, and easy to understand. Its a two part article; part one gets it working minimally, part two goes a lot further.

Comment: This page in the 2sxc Tutorials has a ton of info organized fairly well. Its well worth reviewing the whole page regularly. Lots of hidden gems and time-savers. 
https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/tut/quickref